# Pagination with URL Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I get rid of showing the first page in a pretty url with pagination? For example, I want this to be page 1: `example.com/category/toys/` but I need to specify the first page for it to work: `example.com/category/toys/1`.

My .htaccess code is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*) viewcategory.php?slug=$1&page=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# default: set to page 1
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/?$ viewcategory.php?slug=$1&page=1 [L,QSA,NC]

# when page no. is specified
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ viewcategory.php?slug=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand better now. It doesn't work but I think it is due to my pagination code.